# Can the HP LO100i be used to automatically start and stop a server?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I recently bought a DL160 G6 and i'm looking for a way to automatically start and stop the server at certain hours (which i know is possible with IBMs management modules but i'm not quite sure about HPs LO100i). I've read through the specification and couldn't find anything on that topic. 
If you are using / have access to one of those could you please check if that is a possibility?
Thanks

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing the answer to this too. Your machine should support Wake on LAN though to use in the interim as a workaround.

Comment: @swathe Yes, it supports wake on lan, but i would like to have it shut down and start back up automaticly at 10pm and 1pm even when i'm not at home (For remote access, without it receiving WOLs every couple seconds because i forwarded ports to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any way to do it after browsing through Lights Out on a G7.  I also don't think the bios supports power on/off based on the bios clock.  My best suggestion is to run a scheduled task or script to automatically power off the machine then plug the power supply into some kind of controllable outlet/power strip (http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-7-Day-8-Outlet-Power-Strip-Timer-15077/100685866 or something similar?) and tell the bios to start the host after "power loss" or whatever that setting in the bios is called.

Comment: I could probably setup a cronjob to halt the server at certain hours (Which doesn't turn it off, just shuts the system down or something like that ;) ). When it then looses power you wouldn't have to fear data loss and it would start back up because of that BIOS setting. Although its not that easy because i'm dealing with ESXi here :/